# Реализация динамическое удаление и редактирование Inline кнопки из БД?

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot, telebot, sqlite3, inline

В БД есть таблица, которая содержит в себе text и url, на основе этих параметров в цикле формируется InlineKeyboard, через админ-панель, необходимо реализовать возможность редактирования и удаления этих кнопок. Для удобства при переходе в панель редактирования/удаления должна выводится InlineKeyboard и после нажатия на нужную кнопку она должна удалиться из бд, либо пользователю предлагается изменить text или url.

Comment: в чем вопрос? что не получается?..

Comment: Вопрос в том как организовать callback_data в InlineKeyboardButton, что бы она удалялась из бд при нажатии

Comment: Один из вариантов решения - формировать `callback` наподобие: `callback_data=имя таблицы_идентификатор записи` А потом парсить `callback.data` и сплитнуть это все по `_` То есть `callback.data.split('_')`